# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getPointer

Tags: java, opengl, jar, lwjgl, slick2d

I am running a program fine in the IDE, however out of the IDE in its own jar file, as soon as I export it as a runnable jar file (and make it a fat jar, add the libraries and natives, etc), it gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getPointer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:65)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:81)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:98)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:128)
    at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.setUpDisplay(TerrainDemo.java:1956)
    at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.startGame(TerrainDemo.java:2029)
    at Joehot200.Main.main(Main.java:55)
```

And my set up display method is:

```
private static void setUpDisplay() {
    try {
        DisplayMode displayMode = null;
        DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes(); //this is line 1956

         for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++)
         {
             if (modes[i].isFullscreenCapable())
               {
                    displayMode = modes[i];
               }
         }
         if (displayMode == null){
             displayMode = new DisplayMode(100, 100);
         }
        //Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WINDOW_DIMENSIONS[0], WINDOW_DIMENSIONS[1]));
         Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        Display.setResizable(true);
        Display.setTitle("Pirate game");
        //Display.setFullscreen(true);
        Display.create();

    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        cleanUp(true);
    }
}
```

How can I fix the stupid error and make it work?

Comment: looks like you had a .jar on the path of your ide, which is now missing.

Comment: Since lwjgl uses native libraries (i.e. `.dll`, `.so` etc.) the problem might be that those are not found by your fat jar. So you might need to provide those libraries in a location that can be found by lwjgl.

Comment: @Thomas I have got all natives included from the same folder as the IDE.

Comment: @Stultuske I double-checked, both the IDE and the game have got the Slick library, LWJGL, The same natives folder, LWJGL_Util, and Vecmath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely missing the native libraries. You can set the path to these like this:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("pathToNatives").getAbsolutePath());
```

See [Here](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application)

If you use the folder structure that comes with LWJGL you will have to select the right natives with something like this:

```
        switch(LWJGLUtil.getPlatform())
        {
            case LWJGLUtil.PLATFORM_WINDOWS:
            {
                JGLLib = new File("./native/windows/");
            }
            break;

            case LWJGLUtil.PLATFORM_LINUX:
            {
                JGLLib = new File("./native/linux/");
            }
            break;

            case LWJGLUtil.PLATFORM_MACOSX:
            {
                JGLLib = new File("./native/macosx/");
            }
            break;
        }

        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", JGLLib.getAbsolutePath());
```

And finally: You are using Slick2D so this might be of interest ([Source](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=paormhjm1hm5dr3tg02j4gr0s6&topic=25441.msg219355#msg219355)):

> I looked over the error and figured it must be related to one of the files being older than another, and then I realized that I was using the lwjgl jar that came with slick. I replaced it with the one from the website, and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Not working. Nothing has changed except that I put your line of code (Changing "pathToNatives" to the natives folder path) above the "try{" statement.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that will be useful to me in the future... So an upvote to you - However, it still does not solve the original question :/.

Comment: Do your LWJGL jars and natives version match?

Comment: THANK YOU! I was using different versions of lwjgl_util and slick! This was causing it to crash! Thank you so much for your fix! :)